# I have a bacteria genome, how can I randomly slice it into 150bp-long DNA fragments in python?

Tags: python, random, slice

How can I randomly slice it into 150bp-long fragments in python? I want to slice it for 1000 times and pool all fragments from each time together. This is to computationally mimic Illumina sequencing.

Here is the example:

```
seq = 'ATGGAAAAAGAGTATACGATTGGATTAGATATTGGGACAAATTCGGTTGGATGGGCAGTGTTGACGGATG'
len(seq)=70
```

I want to randomly slice this string into 5 smaller strings with a fixed length 10 without messing up the original orders of the letters. Expected result:

```
seq1= ['ATGGAAAAAG', 'AGTATACGAT', 'TGGATTAGAT', .......]
```

It is like this:

```
seq1= seq[0:10] + seq[10:20] + seq[20:30] + seq[30:40] + seq[40:50]
```

But I want it to be random instead of next to each other.

For seq[n:n+10], n is the starting point of the slicing. I need it to be random, meaning I randomly pick a starting point and take out a 10bp-long DNA slice at that starting point. I then keep slicing the DNA at random starting points.

And then I need to do the same slicing again and again for a total of 10 times:

```
seq2=['', '', '', .....]
seq3=['', '', '', .....]
seq4=['', '', '', .....]
seq5=['', '', '', .....]
seq6=['', '', '', .....]
seq7=['', '', '', .....]
seq8=['', '', '', .....]
seq9=['', '', '', .....]
seq10=['', '', '', .....]
```

And then pool seq1 - seq10 together.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Comment: Try https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just pick a random starting point, and create a substring from there.
Your starting point would exclude the last 150 characters, due to sample length.

I would then make a list for easy manipulation later.

(I create a random DNA string below for testing.)

```
from random import randint, choice

#just for testing we will assign seq randomly.
seq = ''.join(choice(['A', 'C', 'G', 'T']) for pony in range(1000))

sample_length = 150
number_of_samples = 1000

samples = []

for pony in range(number_of_samples):
    sample_start = randint(0, len(seq) - sample_length)
    samples += [seq[sample_start:sample_start+sample_length]]

print(samples[0])
print(samples[1])
```

If you need to do this multiple times, you can always put the above in a function then do something like:

```
samples_list = [do_func() for pony in range(10)]
```

Comment: What on Earth is going on here? how can you start somewhere randomly in DNA and expect reasonable results?

Comment: No idea.  I'm guessing this is just for random samples.  Though this could produce overlapping samples.

Comment: The OP wanted random samples, and the example given appears to be random starting indexes. `seq1= ['ATGGAAAAAG', 'TACGATTGGA', 'GTTGGATGGG', .......]`

Comment: Yeah, I reread the question after posting last comment and realised that it's tough to actually understand what is requested

Comment: I have no idea what the purpose is, but it seems to just be a question about taking random samples from DNA (a string of GATC), which appears to me to have a simple answer.

Comment: Thank you, Paul, your understanding is correct. Sorry for the confusing explanation. I'm trying hard to make it sound clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
#calculate how much extra space there is
extra_length = total_length-string_count*string_length
#choose how to allocate extra space
gaps = np.random.choice(extra_length,string_count)
gaps.sort()
gaps = np.diff(gaps)
#we now have a list of random numbers that add up to extra_length
start = 0
end = start+string_length
seq1 = [seq[start:end]]
for string_index in range(string_count-1):
   #each string skips a random distance determined by our gaps variable
   start = end+gaps[string_index]
   end = start+string_length
   seq1.append(seq[start:start+string_length])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I got Paul's answer working pretty well.